# Cause of thumping noise and resistance to rotation by rotor in Fisher Paykel AquaSmart top loading washer?

Tags: appliances, washing-machine, troubleshooting, laundry

I have a Fisher/Paykel AquaSmart top loading washer model WL37T26CW2. Since about 3 months the direct drive makes a thumping noises during wash / spin cycles, and makes thumping noises and shows occasional resistance to rotation when inner basket is rotated by hand at >30 RPMs.

I did a [bunch of troubleshooting and investigation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/244273/cause-of-recurring-out-of-balance-during-wash-spin-cycle-in-fisher-paykel-aqua) using the service manual and helpful advice in this forum and from YouTube. None of these ideas led to a clear cause and solution so I went further and disassembled the bits attached to the direct drive.

After removing the inner basket, when rotating the shaft (inside the outer basket) or the rotor by hand, the direct drive still makes the same thumping noise and has occasional resistance 2-3 times per rev to rotation.

After removing the rotor, when rotating the shaft by hand the direct drive no longer makes the same thumping noise and has no occasional resistance to rotation.

I inspected the rotor and stator for signs of misalignment, wear and tear, damage, but didn't see anything obvious.

What would cause the rotor to make a thumping noise and exhibit resistance to rotation?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Telescope2334 This is a follow up to my earlier question, with focus on different potential cause for fault.

Comment: Sounds like bearings - but you should kniw that by now if you have been following the manual as it will tell you how to test. ie run out etc

Comment: @SolarMike Why would noise and resistance disappear upon removing rotor if it's bearings?

Comment: No load on them… now you have it apart, just buy and fit new bearings anyway.

Comment: Hi @JohnC, just logged back in to find this. I hope you have had some luck fixing it. I see others suggested replacing the bearing and I think that is logical. In fact by process of elimination it is almost the only thing left to try. Other than the thumping noise, do you hear grinding or squeaky metal-on-metal sounds? Anyway, good luck...